# CIImage is blank when trying to use it with texture obtained from video file frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, core-image

I am trying to create an app which applies filters to video files. I want to use core image filters

```
    imageBuffer obtained from AVAssetReaderInput

    int height = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    int width = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    CVReturn error;
    CVOpenGLESTextureRef _textureRef;
    error = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                          self.openGLContext.textureCache,
                                                          imageBuffer,
                                                          NULL, // texture attributes
                                                          GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                          GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                                          width,
                                                          height,
                                                          GL_BGRA,
                                                          GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // native iOS format
                                                          0,
                                                          &_textureRef);

    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Error while creating Texture");
    }


    glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_textureRef), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_textureRef));
    GLint texture = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_textureRef);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.openGLContext.context options:nil];

    CIImage *my_image = [CIImage imageWithTexture:texture size:CGSizeMake(1280, 720) flipped:NO colorSpace:nil];
```

The CIImage (my_image) is always blank (i.e. it appears black) and does not contain the video texture.
I am testing it on a iPhone 6 device.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this to create your CIImage:

```
     CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer options:nil];
```

You can apply your filters to this image.